# Is there a way that I can the input field text when the field is focussed?

Tags: flutter

I have the following inputfield

```
  child: TextFormField
  (
    decoration: InputDecoration
    (
      hintText: 'Enter your name',
      labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      helperStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      prefixStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      counterStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      suffixStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      errorStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      border: OutlineInputBorder
      (
        borderSide: BorderSide
        (
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
          width: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder
      (
        borderSide: BorderSide
        (
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
          width: 2.0,
        ),
      )
    ),
    validator: (value) {
      return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your name' : null;
    },
  ),
```

When I render it it's height is way to big.

[image]

The I noticed that when I type something the text is huge

[image]

I tried changing all he styles but nothing helps. How can I that text smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the font size of TextFormField, not the decoration:

```
TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8), // set your font size here
    decoration: InputDecoration
    ( ...
```

PS

> 'body1' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This is the term used in
>   the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is bodyText2.
>   This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8

Comment: Thanks for the tip!